# Converte String to byte array and vice versa

Tags: java, arrays

I am a beginner in java I want to convert String to a byte array and vice versa. when I compare the result input_bytes with output.getBytes(). I found that they are not compatible. this is my code.

```
    String input = "bg@%@bg0";
    byte[] input_bytes = input.getBytes();
    String output = new String(input_bytes);
    System.out.println(input_bytes);
    System.out.println(output.getBytes());
```

the result :

```
[B@15db9742
[B@6d06d69c
```

How can I get the same byte array from input and output? and what is the problem in my code?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert a String to a byte array and then back to the original String](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7947871/convert-a-string-to-a-byte-array-and-then-back-to-the-original-string)

Answer (score 4):

Try:

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(input_bytes));
```

You need to use `Arrays.toString()` method.

**Output:** `[98, 103, 64, 37, 64, 98, 103, 48]`

**Note:** Here `Arrays.toString(byte[])` returns a string representation of the contents of the specified `byte array`.

Comment: Having an array `toString()` print its object ID by default instead of the contents of the array probably wasn't a great design decision.

Comment: `Arrays.toString` prints its content, not ID.